# Remove a version of cabal

Tags: uninstallation, cabal

I accidentally installed cabal twice. I did this by:

```
cabal install cabal-install
sudo cabal install cabal-install
```

Now I have two versions of cabal and two versions of each package and it's causing headaches. I want to completely remove cabal from my system (and all packages therein) in order to restart so I don't have two versions. Is this possible and if so, how can I do it?

(Alternatively, I wouldn't mind removing the root version and keeping only the local user version so that I can get xmobar to work without needing to sudo.)

I guess I should note that I have ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have two versions of each package with this. Different `cabal-install` binaries share the same user packagedb just fine. *However*, different users will have different packagedbs. For each user, the user packagedb will be by default in `~/.cabal/lib/` and `~/.cabal/store/` (the latter for `new-build` only).

The bin dir that cabal puts binaries in, including those from `cabal install cabal-install` is in `~/.cabal/bin`. So you can remove the program from either of those bindirs. But you really don't need to remove it from anywhere. Rather, you should just make sure you only ever run it as either root or as local user. But if you really want, you can clear the entire `~/.cabal/` directory from the root user only.

Comment: The issue is that I am actually seeing two different package versions. In particular, xmobar. In my local I have an older version and in the root version I have a new version. I can freely switch between the two (which is nice for some testing purposes) but I'm running into other problems because of this splitting.

Comment: Right -- as I explained, this isn't due to two different cabal install binaries, it is due to two different packagedbs for different users. It would occur even if you only had one packagedb. If you don't want to use the root packagedb, just don't ever invoke cabal as root!